# Git workflow issue on Azure DevOps

Tags: git, azure-devops, git-workflow

I am using the following workflow with Git on Azure DevOps.

I have two branches, `main` and `develop`. When it's time for a release, I create a release branch `rb` from `develop` and open a pull request into the `main` branch. When ready, I merge then with no fast forward.
After the release, I merge `main` into `develop` with the same strategy, no fast forward.

We associate the work items we have been worked on in every commit. So when I open the Pull Request `rb` > `main` I can see the full list of work items involved.

The weird thing is, on the first release all went fine. On the following ones, when I open the Pull Request `rb` > `main` the UI in Azure DevOps shows me as I am trying to merge not just the Work Items of the current release branch, but also those of the previous releases!

The problem goes away if I rebase `develop` over `main` after I merge `main` > `develop` after the release, but I don't think that is the right thing to do. I think I misinterpreting the correct way to manage the workflow with Azure Devops. Can anyone explain me what am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: This is hard to believe unless subsequent PR's of `rb` into `main` also include the old commits you thought you already merged. Does it? If the old commits are also there, then that's the real issue, and the work items showing up is just a symptom of that.

Comment: Some possible causes: 1) if either `rb`, `develop`, or `main` ever get rebased some commits would possibly get merged in again. (Hint, don't ever rebase any of those branches.) 2) If an old work item is associated with a commit on `develop` after `rb` is (re)created, it would show up in the next release branch too. Maybe some devs are simply re-using the same work item and it spans multiple releases.

Comment: What happens if you do a plain merge without going through Azure? i.e. something like `git checkout main && git merge rb`. What does the history look like afterwards?

Comment: If you don't want to mess up your "official" history you can experiment with `git checkout -b merge-test main && git merge rb`.